# PlayFramework MongoDB Project Setup Failed

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, play-reactivemongo

I tried setting up a new Play Framework on Scala and MongoDB. I tried all documentation available online, but each time I tried running the project on the terminal I get some obscure error. I have tried to make sense out of it, but all effort prove abortive. I am new Scala and Play Framework developer. Below is the response am getting from the terminal. Thanks

```
 http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/reactive_mongo_plugin/reactive_mongo_plugin_2.10/0.0.43/reactive_mongo_plugin_2.10-0.0.43.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.trace#trace-sigar-libs;0.1.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: reactive_mongo_plugin#reactive_mongo_plugin_2.10;0.0.43: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: reactive_mongo_plugin#reactive_mongo_plugin_2.10;0.0.43: not found
[error] Total time: 36 s, completed Apr 4, 2015 10:04:19 AM
```

Comment: @cchantep Why do you remove general tags like [playframework]? It makes questions less visible because people who don't follow version-specific tags might not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you try to use the Play plugin, but the dependency doesn't correspond to this lib whose latest artifact is `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"`: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Creactivemongo

Comment: This answer is accepted, but what was the solution to fix this error? I have having the same proglem and looking for an answer of how to solve it. Thank you.